# Absolutely positioned drop down menu different in IE

Tags: css

I have a dropdown menu that behaves fine everywhere (even Edge!) except for IE11.

The dropdown menu has:

```
position: absolute;
left: auto;
top: --nav-height;
```

I can see that in IE11 it aligns itself to the right of the box border of Root A, which seems to indicate that it's not really absolutely positioning itself...

The code is from [this codepen](https://codepen.io/joslex/pen/adeJeV) but I can't get it to work at all on IE11

**All other browsers:**

[image: Correct behaviou]

**IE11**

[image]

Comment: Why `left: auto;` and not `left: 0;`?

Comment: @Paulie_D `left: 0;` sends it way too far over to the left. I don't actually have `left` even set, `auto` is the browser default

Comment: Then it sounds though there is a positioning context issue. Is the parent `li` set as `relative`?

Comment: @Paulie_D thanks, just needed to make the parent position relative and left 0 works!

Comment: Please provide a proper [mre] of your problem, and don’t just refer to a codepen that refuses to even work at all in IE 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add **`position:relative`** to the containing elements of your submenu element, in your case i think it contented in the element showing the `Root A` text, than you can apply **`left:0px`** to the submenu element.

It is important to understand that a value of **`left:0px`** is set equal to the left of it's **parent element**, **not the page**.

And setting **`position:relative`** on a the parent element sets the bounds of an absolutely positioned element equal to the parent element.